# How can I collapse table rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table and I need to collapse each row to show specific info. I've tried several methods but nothing seems to be working. It seems very easy but I can't make it, how can I do that?

This is the tr code:

```
<tr role="row">
   <td>1</td>
   <td class="navtd"><span class="tableinfo">Curating</span></td>
   <td>The Book Affair</td>
   <td>Automatic Books</td>
   <td>2009</td>
</tr>
```

And this is a method I am using to collapse the header, which is working just fine:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("about");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = document.getElementById("aboutPanel");
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<section class="header">


  <div class="menu">
    <table class="nav">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 5%"></td>
          <td class="navtd" style="width: 17.5%"></span>Tommaso Speretta</td>
          <td class="navtd" style="width: 35%"><span class="about"><span>About/Contact</span></span></td>
          <td style="width: 35%"></td>
          <td style="width: 7.5%"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="aboutPanel">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 5%"></td>
          <td style="width: 17.5%"></td>
          <td style="width: 35%">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat
            a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci
            ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi!
          </td>
          <td style="width: 35%">
            <div><img src="img/profilepic.png" alt="Profile picture Tommaso Speretta" class="profilepic"></div>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 7.5%"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, missing tags - and why have divs in cells? Also what is your expected result?

Comment: Is this something that actually needs to be a table? This appears that you _might_ be using tables for layout.

Comment: [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u6zrLadk/). I'm not sure what your overall goal is, but you can see the HTML fixes and jQuery function as a starting point.

Comment: To be honest, it's not clear what you mean by "collapse each row to show specific info"

Comment: [Here's another demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/y0k3v76u/) that toggles rows based on index. It's a much better approach than trying to track IDs or other attributes.

Comment: @hungerstar thanks for your reply. I am using a table because I also need to sort each column, so that seemed the easiest way to do that. But actually, I really don't know if that's the best way.

Comment: @isherwood thank you very much for the fixes. My goal is actually to have a table with sortable columns and collapsible rows to show the specs of each "job".

Comment: @freedomn-m with collapsible rows I actually meant something like the collapse funtion in Bootstrap applied to table rows

Comment: @mplungjan what I'd like to achieve is a table where each column is sortable (ascending or descending) and each row collapse to show the specs of that same row.